# Writing a CTE query the records are duplicated and in the wrong order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that has the data in rows and the data needs to be summarized in columns. Currently the data does go in columns but the data duplicates and is in the wrong order. Also when I enter more than one server name I will get the server 1 column with info Server 2 column will be null and server 3 column will have data.

I have looked at answers on stackoverflow, social.msdn.microsoft.com , sqlservercentral.com and sqlshack.com

```
WITH 
cte (Captivate_Id, Building_Name ,Server_Name,Server_Number)
as

   (
     SELECT b.[Captivate_Id], b.[Building_Name] as Building_Name
     ,(s.Server_Name) as Server_Name
     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.Server_Name DESC) AS Server_Number
      FROM [CAP-CORPCRM02].[CAP_ProductionED].dbo.server s
      join [CAP-CORPCRM02].[CAP_ProductionED].dbo.building b on 
      s.building_id = b.building_id
      WHERE s.Server_Name IS NULL
      UNION ALL
      SELECT b.[Captivate_Id], b.[Building_Name] as Building_Name
      ,(s.Server_Name) as Server_Name
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.Server_Name DESC) AS Server_Number 
       FROM [CAP-CORPCRM02].[CAP_ProductionED].dbo.server s
       join [CAP-CORPCRM02].[CAP_ProductionED].dbo.building b on 
        s.building_id = b.building_id

        AND b.Captivate_Id IN 
        (
          'FFF1234'
         )
         )

SELECT Captivate_ID as ID,Building_Name as Building_Name,
(SELECT Server_Name FROM CTE ct WHERE ct.Building_Name=cte.Building_Name 
AND ct.Server_Number=1) Server1,    -----, -- works but order wrong
(SELECT Server_Name FROM CTE ct WHERE ct.Building_Name=cte.Building_Name 
AND ct.Server_Number=2) Server2, -- works but order wrong
(SELECT Server_Name FROM CTE ct WHERE ct.Building_Name=cte.Building_Name 
AND ct.Server_Number=3) Server3

FROM cte
```

Output

```
ID  Building_Name   Server1     Server2     Server3 
FFF1234 some name   servername1 servername2 NULL    
FFF1234 some name   servername1 servername2 NULL
```

I expect the output to be

```
ID  Building_Name   Server1     Server2     Server3 
FFF1234 some name   servername1 servername2 blank
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would really help here. Also, as an FYI, 2008 has about 6 weeks left of support, so you might want to consider looking at upgrade paths very soon.

Comment: you query don't have "order by", so any order is correct. You need to use ORDER BY to enforce order of rows.

Answer (score 2):

You have a misconception on how `ROW_NUMBER()` works. With two distinct `ROW_NUMBER()` commands, you have two separate row number sequences. You can correct your issue by changing your CTE like this:

```
WITH cte1 (Captivate_Id, Building_Name ,Server_Name)
    AS (
        SELECT b.[Captivate_Id], b.[Building_Name] as Building_Name
            ,'' as Server_Name    -- If you want a blank servername, make it so
        FROM [CAP-CORPCRM02].[CAP_ProductionED].dbo.server s
        join [CAP-CORPCRM02].[CAP_ProductionED].dbo.building b 
            on     s.building_id = b.building_id
        WHERE s.Server_Name IS NULL

        UNION ALL

        SELECT b.[Captivate_Id], b.[Building_Name] as Building_Name
            ,(s.Server_Name) as Server_Name
        FROM [CAP-CORPCRM02].[CAP_ProductionED].dbo.server s
        join [CAP-CORPCRM02].[CAP_ProductionED].dbo.building b 
            on s.building_id = b.building_id
        AND b.Captivate_Id IN (
            'FFF1234'
            )
    ),
cte (Captivate_Id, Building_Name ,Server_Name, Server_Number)
    as (
        SELECT Captivate_ID,
            Building_Name,
            Server_Name,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.Server_Name DESC) AS Server_Number 
        FROM cte1
    )

SELECT Captivate_ID as ID,Building_Name as Building_Name,
    (SELECT Server_Name FROM CTE ct WHERE ct.Building_Name=cte.Building_Name AND ct.Server_Number=1) Server1,-----, -- works but order wrong
    (SELECT Server_Name FROM CTE ct WHERE ct.Building_Name=cte.Building_Name AND ct.Server_Number=2) Server2, -- works but order wrong
    (SELECT Server_Name FROM CTE ct WHERE ct.Building_Name=cte.Building_Name AND ct.Server_Number=3) Server3
FROM cte
```

*SPOILER - Original bad code*

> WITH 
>   cte (Captivate_Id, Building_Name ,Server_Name, Server_Number)
>  as (
>   SELECT Captivate_ID,
>       Building_Name,
>       Server_Name,
>       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.Server_Name DESC) AS Server_Number 
>   FROM (
>       SELECT b.[Captivate_Id], b.[Building_Name] as Building_Name
>           ,'' as Server_Name      -- If you want a blank servername, make it so
>   --      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.Server_Name DESC) AS Server_Number 
>       FROM [CAP-CORPCRM02].[CAP_ProductionED].dbo.server s
>       join [CAP-CORPCRM02].[CAP_ProductionED].dbo.building b 
>           on  s.building_id = b.building_id
>       WHERE s.Server_Name IS NULL
>       UNION ALL
>       SELECT b.[Captivate_Id], b.[Building_Name] as Building_Name
>           ,(s.Server_Name) as Server_Name
>   --      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.Server_Name DESC) AS Server_Number 
>       FROM [CAP-CORPCRM02].[CAP_ProductionED].dbo.server s
>       join [CAP-CORPCRM02].[CAP_ProductionED].dbo.building b 
>                  on s.building_id = b.building_id
>                  AND b.Captivate_Id IN (
>                      'FFF1234'
>                      )
>                  )
>   )

Comment: You are correct I do have a misunderstanding. thanks for clearing it up. I am getting an error      Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 26
Incorrect syntax near ')'. It looks  like I do have the correct number of parentheses, what else could it be?

Comment: Oh, shoot. Looks like the CTE doesn't like the nested SELECT statements.  Editing above to offer corrected code:

Comment: when looking at the code with cte   cte is underlined and saying not recognized as a table hint

Comment: Also  (Captivate_Id, Building_Name ,Server_Name, Server_Number) 
  as ( SELECT Captivate_ID, Building_Name, Server_Name, are all all select values are underlined saying invalid column names and the first line is underlined saying incorrect syntax expecting (

Comment: Table1 -name: Building building_id varchar(50), Building_Name varchar(50), Cap_ID varchar(50)                Table 2- name : Server  Building_ID varchar(50), Server_Name varchar(50)

Comment: Table Building Building_ID 350,650,920  Building_Name Oil_Tower,Gas_Tower,Electric_Tower.   Cap_ID OIL001,GAS001,ELC001

Comment: Table Server Building_ID 650,650,650  Server_Name GT_001,GT_002,GT_003

Comment: Results:    ID         Building_Name Server1 Server2 Server3
                 Gas001 Gas_Tower          GT-003 GT-002 GT-001
                 Gas001 Gas_Tower          GT-003 GT-002 GT-001
                 Gas001 Gas_Tower          GT-003 GT-002 GT-001

Comment: The results I want are:                                                                                       
 ID         Building_Name Server1 Server2 Server3
Gas001 Gas_Tower          GT-001 GT-002 GT-003
Gas001 Gas_Tower          GT-001 GT-002 GT-003
Gas001 Gas_Tower          GT-001 GT-002 GT-003